# Is menstruation manageable?

Tags: menstrual-cycle, menstruation, uterus

For individuals with heavy flow, menstruation can be extremely taxing.

Are there ways of managing duration and heaviness of the menstruation? 
I know that ibuprofen is prescribed, but how about other medication?

If there's a finite amount of tissue to shed within the uterus, then it would seem that speeding up the sloughing or shedding process would reduce the menstruation period.  But I am not sure how hormones play a role in this and if they purely dictate the process or if perhaps the hormones respond to the uterine waste that needs to be removed.  (Chicken and egg scenario.)

Can the menstrual cycle be managed?

Comment: I think this is a great question, but it comes too close to asking for medical advice, and your final paragraph made it far too broad. I edited it slightly, but if you disagree with my changes you can revert them.

Comment: Hmm, I'd thought that my initial question was much less of a "medical advice" question in that I'm attempting to understand the menstruation process more than simply find an answer as to whether or not aspirin will work, per se. For example, if I can understand the process + whether or not it's finite in nature, I can then go into the aspirin research field & find out more.  Thus, her question was not my question, but rather what led me to ask the question. Does that make sense? I'm fine with asking what you've asked, but I was asking about the process & timing control for more depth...

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but that's far too broad. You're asking for an education. Questions here need to be focused and answerable without writing a textbook.

Comment: I have heavily edited your post. It seems to me that this is an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/353950) and you’re actually asking if the menstruation cycle can be managed at all (and if there‘s some merit to aspirin). Bringing in your friend doesn’t really add anything to the discussion, so I removed that section entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Heave menstruation can be a pathology, which is called menorrhagia.

There is a multitude of medication available:

- NSAIDs, such as ibuprofen (Advil, Motrin IB, others) or naproxen sodium (Aleve), help reduce menstrual blood loss. NSAIDs have the added benefit of relieving painful menstrual cramps (dysmenorrhea).
- Tranexamic acid (Lysteda) only needs to be taken during the menstrual phase.
- Oral contraceptives can help regulate menstrual cycles apart from being birth control.
- The hormone progesterone can help correct hormone imbalance and thus reduce menorrhagia.
- Intrauterine devices can release a type of progestin called levonorgestrel, which makes the uterine lining thin and decreases menstrual blood flow and cramping.

<sup>[Source: MayoClinic.org](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/menorrhagia/diagnosis-treatment/drc-20352834), [MedScpae.com](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/255540-treatment)</sup>

However, this is something to consult a gynaecologist with. Menorrhagia can also lead to anaemia (a decrease of red blood cells in the blood), if the body can't keep up with the heavy bleeding.